# Cannot hide editButtonItem in moreNavigationController for the FIRST time

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am using this code (self is my TabBarController)

self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

the editButtonItem is getting hidden if I double click on the more button or get back to "more" view, but it is shown the first time no matter where I put this code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing it inside `ViewWillappear` ?